# shebang changed to /usr/libexec/platform-python when building python rpm packages

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build a  RPM from a python application on RHEL8.2 machine.

the shebang on the scripts are set correctly to `#!/usr/bin/python3`
however for some reason the shebang gets changed to `#!/usr/libexec/platform-python -s` when the RPM is built.

I have tried almost everything.

I have undefined the mangling according to doc: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/packaging_and_distributing_software/advanced-topics

```
 %undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs
```

but the shebangs gets still changed.

this is the relevant parts of the specs file:

```
%undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs
Name: myapp
Version: 2.0.0
Release: 1%{?dist}
summary: rpm for my APP

BuildArch: noarch

### Build Dependencies ###
BuildRequires: python3-setuptools
BuildRequires: python3-devel

%?python_enable_dependency_generator

%build
%py3_build


%install
%py3_install

%files
....
```

I can include `python*-rpm-macros` to the specs and that would set the shebang to something like `/usr/bin/python3.6` but it is  too restrictive. Our code works in anything > python3.6 so if we deploy the rpm in a system with python3.8 it should work.

how can I set /usr/bin/python3 or leave the shebang unchanged on the python scripts? when the rpm is packaged?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same exact issue. Here is a workaround for posterity.

If the python file (or whatever file) has executable permissions set, then the mangling will kick in. So we can make it so that when it is packaging, the file is not executable, but after installation it becomes executable.

1. Remove the executable permission on the python file. `chmod -x script.py`
2. Modify the post section of your spec file as follows.

```
%post
chmod +x /your/installation/path/script.py
```